# Array to string conversion

Tags: php, arrays, string, preg-match-all

What's the problem of this code?
I don't get it. 
This is the error code:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\stage\ripper.php on line 12 Array 
>   Blockquote
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\stage\ripper.php
>   on line 13 Array

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$url = "http://www.asaphshop.nl/epages/asaphnl.sf/nl_NL/ObjectPath=/Shops/asaphnl/Products/80203122";
$htmlcode = file_get_contents($url);
$pattern = "/itemprop=\"description\"\>(.*)\<\/div\>(.*)\<li\>Taal:(.*)\<\/li\>(.*)\>(.*)\<\/div\>\<li\>(.*)\data-src-l\<\/li\>/sU";
preg_match_all($pattern, $htmlcode, $matches);
Print_r ($matches);
$description =($matches[1]);
$language = ($matches[3]);
echo $description;
echo $language
?>
```

Comment: What are the brackets doing around the operands in lines 12 & 13?

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex is a hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239)
HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.
See: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `preg_match_all`, `$matches` is a 2-dimensional array. So `$matches[1]` and `$matches[3]` are both arrays. `echo` only works with numbers or strings, so you get a warning when you try to echo an array. If you want to see what's in them, use `print_r()` or `var_dump()`:

```
print_r($description);
print_r($language);
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! but all my arrays are empty while there should be a lot of text inside them. how do i solve this?

Comment: If they're empty it's because those parts of the regexp aren't matching anything.

Answer (score 0):

It seems $language is an array. So to print a array you either loop through it and echo each element, or you can use print_r.
Other than that you can use var_dump($language) which will tell you what type it is and what it's content is . Or you can go for json_encode($language).

Hope it helps :)