# Can't acces to values from array - PHP

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
$arr = array();

$dns_1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$dns_2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$d1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dns_1);
$d2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dns_2);

$arr[1] = $d1;
$arr[2] = $d2;

foreach($arr as $key => $values) {
            echo $key."".$values;
        }
```

Output:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 79
1Array
```

Why can't I `echo` the `$values` in my `foreach`??

I don't want to use implode if possible

Thank you!

Comment: As the notice says, `$values` is an associative array (as defined when you called `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`), not a string. So you either need to do `echo $key." ".implode($values, " ");` or iterate over `$values` and output them individually.

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of running the same query twice? Or are you changing the query between the two `mysqli_query` calls, but you've omitted it from the question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array to string conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26377015/array-to-string-conversion) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `$values` is an array, you can't echo it as a string. If you don't want to use `implode()`, you can use `print_r()` like this:

```php
foreach($arr as $key => $values) {
    echo $key . ':';
    print_r($value);
}
```